# clusterssh: prevent windows being arranged alphabetically

Tags: shell, ssh, perl, cluster-ssh

I am using `cssh` on Debian 10 (package `clusterssh 4.13.2-2`).

when I connect to multiple servers:

```
cssh foo bar zz aa
```

cssh will open 4 terminals and **ORDERS THEM ALPHABETICALLY !!!**
So that I get the windows ordered on my screen as follows:

```
aa   bar
foo  zz
```

This is pure evil !

How can I keep the windows in original order?
Is there some quick fix in the perl code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the approximate [source](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/blob/4.13_test_fix/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm#L110), we can see that there is an array `@servers` that seems to hold the original host name arguments in their given order, and a hash (unsorted dictionary) `%servers` that holds all the per-host info, indexed by a key derived from the hostname.

In [open_client_windows](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/blob/4.13_test_fix/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm#L670), which seems to be called with the ordered array of names, we have the creation of each `%servers` entry.

In `retile_hosts()`, the windows are opened in the order given by `$sort->( keys(%servers) )`, code starting from [here](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/blob/4.13_test_fix/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm#L1101), hence the order you see.

So a possible solution is to preserve, in an extra field of each server entry, the order in which it was created, and then change the `$sort` function so that it sorts on this value instead of the key. (Changing the key would be simpler, but it is used a lot, and might have unknown consequences.).

The following patch works on my Fedora 28 version of `ClusterSSH.pm`. You may need to change this for your distributed version.

```perl
--- usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/App/ClusterSSH.pm.orig  2022-08-24 10:47:57.937143651 +0200
+++ usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/App/ClusterSSH.pm   2022-08-24 11:32:43.637808164 +0200
@@ -116,9 +116,12 @@
 my $host_menu_static_items;    # number of items in the host menu that should
                                # not be touched by build_host_menu
 my (@dead_hosts);              # list of hosts whose sessions are now closed
-my $sort = sub { sort @_ };   # reference to our sort function which may later
+#my $sort = sub { sort @_ };   # reference to our sort function which may later
                               # be changed in run() if the user has asked for
                               # natural sorting
+# sort using original order of cli args 
+# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714683/119298
+my $sort = sub { sort {$servers{$a}{order} <=> $servers{$b}{order}} @_ };
 
 $keysymtocode{unknown_sym} = 0xFFFFFF;    # put in a default "unknown" entry
 $keysymtocode{EuroSign}
@@ -667,6 +670,8 @@
     #$xdisplay->flush(); # dont flush here, but after all tiling worked out
 }
 
+# sort using original order of cli args
+my $globalorder;
 sub open_client_windows(@) {
     my $self = shift;
     foreach (@_) {
@@ -727,6 +732,8 @@
         $servers{$server}{port}           = $port || '';
         $servers{$server}{master}         = $self->config->{mstr} || '';
         $servers{$server}{master}         = $master if ($master);
+        # sort using original order of cli args
+        $servers{$server}{order}          = ++$globalorder;
 
         $self->debug( 2, "Working on server $server for $_" );
```

Comment: that works beautifully. Thank you